# Change: Quality Gate from Jenkins (sonar-runner)

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am using Jenkins to kick off Sonar-runner for analyzing projects.

Now I use the **Build Breaker** plugin.
This breaks a build when a quality gate is reporting that the quality is below/above given values.

I'd like to change the quality gate used by the Sonar-Runner, on a per-job basis in Jenkins.
Looking up at [Analysis Parameters](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) documentation:

```
**sonar.profile** parameter is to change the language to analyse
```

I would thought that for the gate: **sonar.gate** would work (it doesn't)

---

Question:

What parameter for sonar-runner has to be used to change the "Quality Gate"?

Used versions:

- Jenkins 1.598
- Sonar 4.5.1 (LTS)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The property is `sonar.qualitygate`.

It was not documented because this is generally not a good idea to change the quality gate that should be used during a standard analysis - but it's true that it can be useful with the build breaker on *preview* analyses.

I updated the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback: It won't work with spaces inside the qualitygate name i try using **" ",' ',_ and nothing** all giving can't find qualitygate. When i did manage to change the qualitygate it doesn't show the last used qualitygate on the Dashboard.

Comment: If your quality gate has a space (for instance "My Gate"), you just have to encode the space character (i.e. "My%20Gate").

Comment: For selecting a profile there was a solution to use **"I do like spaces"**. And for the dashboard not showing the last used qualitygate?

Comment: That's weird, you should create a new question and paste the logs there so that I can check.

Comment: Using 4.4.1 it complains if the qualitygate named does not exist, but if it does exist then that is not set on the project.

Comment: Can the current docs be updated to mention this setting? It's a useful feature for analysis run on temporary branches of source code. Sonar project is created when Git branch is created and both are deleted when branch is merged into master. In our use case we don't want devs to manually set the quality gate for each branch, config setting is ideal in our case. For anyone else looking for the docs mention, they're only in the 5.0 version http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE50/Analysis+Parameters

Comment: The log showed it is loaded a custom quality gate; but it really did not, sonar ui so it used the default quality gate.

Answer (score 0):

I tried above solution but it did not work for me. Finally I figured out that with new version of sonar-scanner we can achieve it only from Sonar-Qube UI. 
Follow below steps:

1. Login to Sonar Quber server as administrator and select projects. Search for the project name you want to add the quality gate for. Select the searched project and below screen screen would appear.
   [image]
2. Navigate to Administration > Quality Gates
   [image]
3. Select the quality gate from the drop-down which you want to use for this project (A default quality gate is assigned by-default for all the projects).

   [image]

Hope this helps. Thanks!